# Repetição duplicada

Tags: php, mysql, loop, foreach

Estou com um problema na repetição do meu resultado, na verdade não estou conseguindo encontra uma solução percebam que nessa imagem abaixo temos o numero do pedido e as parcelas, porém esse numero de pedido sempre repete quando a uma nova parcela, quero que ele não se repita que fique apenas 1 vez a baixo dele as parcelas do próprio, tentei por um outro `foreach` dentro em baixo do número de pedido mas não funciono, alguém pode me ajudar?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Codigo:

```
<?php
    $Cod = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'cod', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
    if ($Cod):
        $ReadCheck = new Read;
        $Hoje = date('Y-m-d');
        $N = "N";
        $ReadCheck->ExeRead("c022vdpr", "WHERE cod_cliente = :cod AND vct_parcela < :vct AND quitacao = :quit", "cod={$Cod}&vct={$Hoje}&quit={$N}");
        if ($ReadCheck->getResult()):
            $read = new Read;
            $read->ExeRead("c002clie", "WHERE codigo = :cod", "cod={$Cod}");
            if ($read->getResult()):
                $Nome = $read->getResult()[0]['razao'];
            endif;
            echo " <table style=\"width: 100%; text-align: left\" >
                    <thead><th style=\"width: 50%;\">Nome</th><td colspan=\"2\" style=\"width: 50%;\">{$Nome}</td></thead>";

            foreach ($ReadCheck->getResult() as $Pedidos):
                extract($Pedidos);
                ?>

                <thead><th>Pedido</th><td><?php echo $nro_pedido ?></td></thead>
                <?php
                $ReadParce = new Read;
                $ReadParce->ExeRead("c022vdpr", "WHERE nro_pedido = :ped", "ped={$nro_pedido}");
                ?>
                <thead><th>Vencimento</th><th>Valor</th><th>N° Parcela</th></thead>
<tr><td><?php echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime($vct_parcela)); ?></td><td>R$ <?php echo $vlr_parcela ?></td><td><?php echo $nro_parcela ?></td></tr>
                <tr><td colspan="3" style="background-color: #ccc; padding: 3px;"></td></tr>
                <?php
            endforeach;
        endif;
    endif;
    ?>
    </table>
```

Comment: Já tentou colocar apenas a linha referente ao número do pedido fora do `foreach`?

Comment: Então o pior é que tenho que por no foreach se não, a repetição não vai funcionar, é que esta tudo em uma tabela

Comment: http://i68.tinypic.com/qn304l.jpg

Comment: Mas o objetivo não é deixar de repetir o número do pedido?

Comment: Sim, mas no banco está junto o numero de parcelas e o numero de pedido tipo: 
1 linha = numero de pedido 1234, numero da parcela 1;
2 linha = numero de pedido 1234, numero da parcela 2;

Comment: O link passado está quebrado. E por quê a primeira parcela deve trazer o número do pedido diferente das demais? Ou são pedidos diferentes mesmo?

Comment: então todas as parcelas traz o numero do pedido por isso ele se repete, mas o que eu fiz, eu coloquei um distinct nro_pedido no meu primeiro select e fiz o foreach, trazendo apenas as numeros de pedidos sem duplicação, so no segundo select eu peguei as parcelas colocando em um segundo foreach e deu certo!

Comment: http://imgur.com/V6mOIWc

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar uma variável passando o número do pedido aí valide se a variável (com o valor do numero do pedido anterior) é igual ao atual do loop (no final do loop guarde o número do pedido na variável, para fazer a próxima comparação e assim sucessivamente):

```
$guardapedido = '';

foreach...

<?php if ($guardapedido != $nro_pedido) { ?>
    <thead><th>Pedido</th><td><?php echo $nro_pedido; ?></td></thead>
<?php } ?>

<?php $guardapedido = $nro_pedido; ?>

...endforeach
```